# Delay javascript code execution inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, timeout, delay

I have the following for loop:

```
for (var i = tileLog.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    $('.' + tileLog[i]).mouseenter();
};
```

1 < tileLog.legth  < 1025

Is there a way to delay each iteration of the loop so that mouseenter() is triggered every x miliseconds?

I have tried:

```
function doSetTimeout(i) {
    setTimeout(function() { $('.' + i).mouseenter(); }, 250);
}

for (var i = tileLog.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  doSetTimeout(tileLog[i]);
```

This doesn't seem to work, it just delays by 250ms then iterates through the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to using `setTimeout()` you could also use `setInterval()`.

Define a running variable in the outer scope (like your running `i` in the loop). 
In each iteration, besides calling your function, decrement the running variable. If it is below zero, stop the setInterval()`` :

```
var index = tileLog.length - 1,
timer = setInterval( function(){

  $('.' + tileLog[index]).mouseenter();

  index -= 1;
  if ( index < 0 ) {
    clearInterval( timer );
  }
}, 250 );
```

There is no actual `sleep()` function or something similar. Would also be problematic as JavaScript (for most cases) is single threaded and such a method would block the render thread, thus rendering your browser inaccessible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no sleep or such in JavaScript. So your approach with timeout is correct.

```
var tileLog;
var i = titleLog.length - 1;

function func1() {
   $('.' + tileLog[i]).mouseenter();
   if (--i) {
     window.setTimeout(func1, 250);
   }
}

// and of course start the process
func1();
```